# awk to print unique latest date & time lines based on column fields

Tags: awk

Would like to print unique lines based on first field AND latest Date & Time of third field, 
keep the latest date and time occurrence of that line and remove duplicate of other occurrences.
Having around 50 million rows , file is not sorted ...

Input.csv

```
10,ab,15-SEP-14.11:09:06,abc,xxx,yyy,zzz
20,ab,23-SEP-14.08:09:35,abc,xxx,yyy,zzz
10,ab,25-SEP-14.08:09:26,abc,xxx,yyy,zzz
62,ab,12-SEP-14.03:09:23,abc,xxx,yyy,zzz
58,ab,22-JUL-14.05:07:07,abc,xxx,yyy,zzz
20,ab,23-SEP-14.07:09:35,abc,xxx,yyy,zzz
```

Desired Output:

```
10,ab,25-SEP-14.08:09:26,abc,xxx,yyy,zzz
20,ab,23-SEP-14.08:09:35,abc,xxx,yyy,zzz
62,ab,12-SEP-14.03:09:23,abc,xxx,yyy,zzz
58,ab,22-JUL-14.05:07:07,abc,xxx,yyy,zzz
```

Have attempeted partial commands  and in-complete due to Date and Time format of the file un sorting order ...

```
awk -F, '!seen[$1,$3]++'  Input.csv
```

Looking for your suggestions ...

Comment: This line `20,ab,23-SEP-14.08:09:35,abc,xxx,yyy,zz` does not exist in original file.

Comment: Jotne , i am having two rows for ID 20: 20,ab,23-SEP-14.08:09:35,abc,xxx,yyy,zzz AND 20,ab,23-SEP-14.07:09:35,abc,xxx,yyy,zzz

Comment: @AVN, since the file is not sorted by date, do you have any control over the file's date format?  The code would be much easier if the date format was amenable to an easy comparison test for newer/older.

Comment: Jotne,sorry, no , i don't have control to change the file's date format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this awk command will do it for you:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=',' '{sub(/[.]/," ",$3);"date -d\""$3"\" +%s"|getline d}
    !($1 in b)||d>b[$1] {b[$1] =d; a[$1] = $0}
    END{for(x in a)print a[x]}' file
```

- first line transforms the original `$3` into valid date format string and get the seconds from 1970 via `date` cmd, so that we could later compare.
- using `a and b` two arrays to hold the final result and the latest date (seconds)
- the `END` block print all rows from `a`

#### test with your example data:

```
kent$  cat f
10,ab,15-SEP-14.11:09:06,abc,xxx,yyy,zzz
20,ab,23-SEP-14.08:09:35,abc,xxx,yyy,zzz
10,ab,25-SEP-14.08:09:26,abc,xxx,yyy,zzz
62,ab,12-SEP-14.03:09:23,abc,xxx,yyy,zzz
58,ab,22-JUL-14.05:07:07,abc,xxx,yyy,zzz
20,ab,23-SEP-14.07:09:35,abc,xxx,yyy,zzz

kent$  awk -F, '{sub(/[.]/," ",$3);"date -d\""$3"\" +%s"|getline d}
        !($1 in b)||d>b[$1]  { b[$1] =d;a[$1] = $0 }
        END{for(x in a)print a[x]}' f
10 ab 25-SEP-14 08:09:26 abc xxx yyy zzz
20 ab 23-SEP-14 08:09:35 abc xxx yyy zzz
58 ab 22-JUL-14 05:07:07 abc xxx yyy zzz
62 ab 12-SEP-14 03:09:23 abc xxx yyy zzz
```

Comment: While executing the above script, got warning like - date: invalid date `+%s'
However got the expected output

From Cygwin Terminal Output for reference:

date: invalid date `+%s'

62,5,12-SEP-14 03:09:23,abc,xxx,yyy,zzz
58,5,22-JUL-14 05:07:07,abc,xxx,yyy,zzz
10,1,25-SEP-14 08:09:26,abc,xxx,yyy,zzz
20,1,23-SEP-14 08:09:35,abc,xxx,yyy,zzz

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
sort -t , -k 3 file | awk -F, '{a[$1]=$0} END {for (i in a) print a[i]}'
62,ab,12-SEP-14.03:09:23,abc,xxx,yyy,zzz
58,ab,22-JUL-14.05:07:07,abc,xxx,yyy,zzz
10,ab,25-SEP-14.08:09:26,abc,xxx,yyy,zzz
20,ab,23-SEP-14.08:09:35,abc,xxx,yyy,zzz
```

Comment: Thanks Jotne , for ID 20 , expected output line is 20,ab,23-SEP-14.08:09:35,abc,xxx,yyy,zzz  which is the latest record

Comment: @AVN Then you need to sort data based on `date` field before you process it with this command. See my updated post.